# Restrict files with Password protection in android kotlin/java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile-development

Geojson and other format files which are being created from my apps in "Android/data/package_folder" should not be access by user directly. whenever user tries to open it in any ways like copy it using USB and use it in other device's app then it should prompt the user to enter a password to access the file.
how can i achieve it.

or

how can i make my whole package_folder from path "Android/data/package_folder" to password protected programmatically.

couldn't get any solution to protect file with password at time of creation and a folder too programmatically.

Comment: Is accessing the files under the app folder using a password an actual feature you want to build, or you're simply looking for a way to prevent access to those files? You can look into encrypting those files instead.

Comment: encryption to each file will me more time and memory consuming which is not idle for my situation.
it'll be good if we can protect them with password or only package folder.